Only a few records can be pagination with standard set controller
What approach do you use when processing > 10000 data in Salesforce?
Well, I try to process each query with limit and pagination from StandardSetController. So every user click next button, I get last ID from record and make it params in query like this:
    public void next(){
        sObject lrds = listRDS.getRecords().get(listRDS.getRecords().size() - 1);
        system.debug(lrds);
        listRDS = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c WHERE Id > :ldrs.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(selectEntries)]));
        listRDS.setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(selectEntries));
        listRDS.setPageNumber(1);
        pageNumber = listRDS.getPageNumber();
    }

This approach to optimize the search process (maybe). But the problem actually occurs when the records that are processed every time user clicks the next button are only 200 records appears, meaning that only pressing next 2 times (with selectEntries value set to 100) then no more data is displayed, even though when I debug, every user clicks the button, the lrds parameter always takes the last data based on what is displayed in the table. Why is this happening?
Here I show you the full version code:
public String searchRDS {get; set;}
    public String selectEntries {get; set;}
    public Integer pageNumber {get; set;}
    public Integer resultSize {get; set;}
    public String firstId {get; set;}
    public String lastId {get; set;}
    public Boolean showExport {get; set;}
    public transient List <RDS_Box__c> findRDS {get; set;}
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController listRDS {get; private set;}
    
    public RDSBoxController() {
        showExport = false;
        selectEntries = '25';
        
        findRDS = [SELECT Id, No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c];
        resultSize = findRDS.size();
        
        showExport = true;
        
        searchRDSBox();
        
    }
    
    public PageReference searchRDSBox() {
        listRDS = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id, No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(selectEntries)]);

        if (String.isNotBlank(searchRDS)) {
            String searchs = '%'+searchRDS.trim()+'%';
            listRDS = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c WHERE Policy_No__c LIKE :searchs OR Queue_No__c LIKE :searchs]);
        }

        return null;
    }
    
    public List<RDS_Box__c> getBoxs() {
        return listRDS.getRecords();
    }
    
    public void entries(){
        listRDS = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id, No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(selectEntries)]);
        listRDS.setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(selectEntries));
        pageNumber = listRDS.getPageNumber();
    }
    
    public void next(){
        sObject lrds = listRDS.getRecords().get(listRDS.getRecords().size() - 1);
        system.debug(lrds);
        listRDS = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c WHERE Id > :lrds.Id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(selectEntries)]));
        listRDS.setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(selectEntries));
        listRDS.setPageNumber(1);
        pageNumber = listRDS.getPageNumber();
    }
    
    public void previous(){
        listRDS = new ApexPages.StandardSetController([SELECT Id, No_Box__c, Policy_No__c, Queue_No__c, Box_Key__c FROM RDS_Box__c WHERE Id < :firstId ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT :Integer.valueOf(selectEntries)]);
        listRDS.setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(selectEntries));
        listRDS.previous();
        pageNumber = listRDS.getPageNumber();
    }
    

And here's the code for VisualForce Page:
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!boxs}" var="rds">
  <apex:column value="{!rds.Policy_No__c}" headerValue="No.Polis"/>
  <apex:column value="{!rds.Queue_No__c}" headerValue="No.Antrian"/>
  <apex:column value="{!rds.No_Box__c}" headerValue="No.Box"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
...
<apex:panelGrid columns="8" style="line-height:2em" border="1">
                <apex:commandButton status="notifyRDS" reRender="rdsList" value="|<" title="First" action="{!first}" disabled="{!NOT(listRDS.hasPrevious)}" styleClass="btn"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="notifyRDS" reRender="rdsList" value="<<" title="Previous" action="{!previous}" disabled="{!NOT(listRDS.hasPrevious)}" styleClass="btn"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="notifyRDS" reRender="rdsList" value=">>" title="Next" action="{!next}" styleClass="btn"/>
                <apex:commandButton status="notifyRDS" reRender="rdsList" value=">|" title="Last" action="{!last}" disabled="{!NOT(listRDS.hasNext)}" styleClass="btn"/>
                <apex:actionStatus id="notifyRDS" startText="Loading..." stopText=" "></apex:actionStatus>
                <apex:outputText >
                    Page {!pageNumber} to
                    {!listRDS.pageSize} of {!resultSize} records
                </apex:outputText>
            </apex:panelGrid>

